# What can one say about the ratio $E[\mathrm{Var}[X\mid \mathcal H]]/E[\mathrm{Var}[X\mid \mathcal G]]$ if $ \mathcal G\subseteq \mathcal H$?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

> Let $\{\mathcal{F}_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ denotee a filtration with $\mathcal{F}_n \subset \mathcal{F}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, on the probability space  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. If $X$ is a square integrable random variable, what can one say, for $m<n$, about the ratio
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}[X\mid \mathcal{F}_n]]} {\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}[X\mid \mathcal{F}_m]]}\ ?$$

*My try:*

Consider $Y_n=\mathrm{Var}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{n})$ for every $n \in\mathbb N$, then

$$\mathrm{E}[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1})\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1})^2\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$$ $$=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}])^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=
\mathrm{E}[X^2-2X\mathrm{E}[X\mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}]+\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]= $$
$$\mathrm{E}[X^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]-\mathrm{E}[2X\mathrm{E}[X\mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal{F}_n]+\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]= X^2-2X^2+\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n] $$
I don't know how to go on

Comment: Is there something wrong in my question as no one answers me?

Comment: People here volunteer to answer, not everybody with the expertise needed necessarily has time today.

Comment: Ok, I asked because is my first time writing here and I thought that made some mistake in the way I posted the question.

Comment: Your fourth equal sign $$\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}])^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal{F}_n])^2\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$$ (where I added some missing parenthesis on the LHS) is wrong since you are replacing $$\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]$$ by $$\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$$ and $$\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\ne\mathrm{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{n+1}]$$ in general. Re the result itself, I would suggest to try to acquire some understanding of  ...

Comment: ... the situation by solving completely the case $m=1$, $n=2$, $X=Z_1+Z_2$ with each $Z_k$ $\mathcal F_k$-measurable. Can you prove the result then? Is anything different happening in the general case?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’m gonna try what you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that, for a general $\mathcal{A}$ sigma algebra,
$$Var[X\vert \mathcal{A}] = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{A}])^2\vert \mathcal{A}]
= \mathbb{E}[X^2\vert \mathcal{A}] - \mathbb{E}[X\vert\mathcal{A}]^2$$
So you have
$$\mathbb{E}[Var[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert\mathcal{F}_n]^2]$$
Now let $Z_n=\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]^2$. Since $\{\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]\}_n$ is a martingale, $Z_n$ is a submartingale, so $\mathbb{E}[Z_n]\geq \mathbb{E}[Z_m]$ for $n>m$. Therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z_n] \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z_m]$$
which gives you
$$ \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[Var[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]]}{\mathbb{E}[Var[X\vert \mathcal{F}_m]]}\leq 1$$
I don't know if this answers your problem completely. I think better results can be achieved, for example probably the sequence $Y_n=Var[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]$ is a supermartingale, and maybe under suitable hypothesis it can also be shown that it converges a.s. to $Var(X)$, which implies that the ratio tends to $1$ as $m, n\to \infty$.

Comment: How can you say that $\{\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]\}_n$ is a martingale?

Comment: This is a standard result for martingales. It uses the tower property for conditional expectation: if $n\geq m$, then$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]\vert \mathcal{F}_m] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_m]\vert \mathcal{F}_n] = \mathbb{E}[X \vert \mathcal{F}_m]$$

Comment: I see. Maybe you can clarify me some doubts: to verify that is a martingale shouldn't we have $E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}]=X_n $? I don't understand how you verified this here

Comment: This is equivalent to more in general show that, if $n\geq m$, then $\mathbb{E}[X_n\vert\mathcal{F}_m]=X_m$. Anyway, once you know it holds for any $n\geq m$, then you can take $n=\widetilde{n}+1$, $m=\widetilde{n}$ and you recover your definition. (here $X_n:=\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_n]$)